# Chrome Extension: pushing information gathered before a new tab is created?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a popup.html which loads a script (popup.js) as its header for the browser action.
This then makes calls to a site to get information necessary.

I got all the information necessary using XMLHTTPRequests and saved it into variables in popup.js.

Now I try to create a new tab, load a webpage and then use the information I saved to fill out a form.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': "https://site.html" });
```

This line is in popup.js

This takes my to the site desired quickly but seems to remove all the information I had previously retrieved. It does not even alert me the information I want even though I ask for it before making the tab. How would I go about creating a tab with a specific url and then using the information I gathered previously in popup.js to fill a form on it all while contained inside popup.js? Is my logic flawed? Thank you so much for any advice.

UPDATE: Ill edit this to make more sense.

this is my popup.js

```
function do(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("Get", Url);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            var dogName = this.responseText;
            alert(dogName)
}
do();
chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': "site.html" });
```

inside  site.html there is a form. I was to do this to that form.

```
document.getElementById('form').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = dogName; 
document.getElementById("btnOK").click()
```

But it wont do anything if the line

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': "https://site.html" });
```

exists, it will only take me to that page and not run `do()` to alert anything.

By removing the create line, the extension alerts me of the information I want.

Comment: given you give it a really short url without any info, what do you except to show?

Comment: no i shorted it quickly lemme fix it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) instead of a popup. The event page is a long-running script that will allow you to retrieve your data on-demand. The tab that is opened will also need to run a content script. This content script will send messages to the event page to retrieve the fetch XHR data and then apply the data to the form fields. [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can be [injected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) using either the manifest.json file or directly on the chrome.tabs.create function passed in as the second argument.

> **Note**: The below code is a close example of how the files and structure
>   should be. It has not been tested and it should be used to get a
>   general idea of the solution.

Manifest.json

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["*://eample.com/formpage.html"],
    "js":         ["content.js"],
    "run_at":     "document_idle"
  }],
```

***OR***

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': "https://example.com/formpage.html" }, function(tab1) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab1.id, {file: 'content.js', run_at});
});
```

---

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: "dogName"}, function(response) {
  var dogName = response.data;
  document.getElementById('form').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = dogName;
});
```

---

event.js

```
function getDogName(callback){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("Get", Url);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        var = dogName = this.responseText;
        callback({data: dogName});
    }
  });
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.data === "dogName") {
      getDogName(sendResponse);
      return true;
    }
});
```

You can find more details about extension communications here: [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Popup will destroy the focus and thus no callback will work as the active tab will now be the site. However, using a background script to open the tabs works fine. Where does event.js get called or function do.

Comment: @Stevie I forgot to change the name of the `do` function to `getDogName`. I updated it. As for the popup, I was thinking that you might have an extension that provides a UI for the user and taking some action will open the new tab. This is still possible as when the user clicks on a button that opens a new tab, the tab will have a content script that can communicate with the event page.